# Two basic conceptions of Galois cohomology.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-cohomology

$\quad$ I started learning $\textbf{Galois Cohomology}$ just 2 days ago and I am now confused with several conceptions. For example, there is a corollary written below.

$\quad$ $\textbf{Corollary}$: Let $\textbf{K}$ be a field of characteristic not dividing $n\geq1$, and suppose that $\textbf{K}$ contains the $n$th roots of unity. The Galois group of the maximal abelian extension of $\textbf{K}$ of exponent $n$ is Kummer dual to $\textbf{$K^{*}/K^{*n}$}$.

$\quad$ $\textbf{Here is my question}$: I know $\textbf{$K^{*}$}$ means the multiplicative group of $K$, but I am not sure what $K^{*n}$ means. In my opinion it means $\{x^{n}\mid x\in K^{*}\}$, and $K^{*}/K^{*n}$ means a quotient group, am I right? And could you give me a concrete example to make me understand it better?

$\quad$ $\textbf{I really appreciate your help.}$ That may seem easy to you, but really makes me confused.

Comment: You are right. As a simple example look at the field of real numbers, and take $n=2$. The squares of non-zero real is simply all positive real. So  the quotient group is all non-zero reals quotiented by positive reals (multiplication of real numbers being the group operation.) This quotient is a group of order 2.